# Hiding popup template in ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup

I am creating a Custom Popup template as follows:

```
countyPop = new PopupTemplate({
            title: "County: {NAME}",
            fieldInfos: [{ 
                fieldName: "POP2000",
                label: "2000 Pop",
                visible: true
            }, {
                fieldName: "POP2010",
                label: "2010 Pop",
                visible: true
            }]
        });
```

This popup works fine and is firing when I click the layer.  However, I have some javascript to switch out the layers and when I hide this layer and show a different shape layer the popup still hangs around.

How can I stop displaying this popup when I switch to a different layer?

I tried

```
countyPop.hide();
```

It states there is a hide method in [infoWindow](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/popup.html#hide) but that does nothing.  No error is produced and the popup is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
map.infoWindow.hide();
```

to hide and close the popup. Popup templates do not have a hide method as they specify how content is displayed, not whether the popup itself is visible.